# Cannot find the DropDownList in DetailView Insert Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, detailview

I created a DetailView which is bound. I would like to have a DropDownList for the ProposalStatus field instead of a TextBox. I can add the DropDownList dynamically, but cannot find the control after clicking the Insert.

Is there way to find the DropDownList in behind code? Or do I have to use the ItemTemplate?

Thank you

test.aspx

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:DetailsView ID="dvProposal" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="100%"
    OnModeChanging="dvProposal_OnModeChanging" OnItemInserting="dvProposal_OnItemInserting"
    OnItemDeleting="dvProposal_OnItemDeleting">
    </asp:DetailsView>
</form>
```

test.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WildfireOperationsResearch"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            dvProposal_DataRebind();
        }
    }

    protected DropDownList LoadProposalStatusDropDownList()
    {
        DropDownList ProposalStatusList = new DropDownList();
        string SelectString = "select ProposalStatus from ProposalStatus order by ProposalStatus";
        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectString, MyConnection);
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();

            MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet);
            ProposalStatusList.DataSource = MyDataSet;
            ProposalStatusList.DataValueField = "ProposalStatus";
            ProposalStatusList.DataTextField = "ProposalStatus";
            ProposalStatusList.ID = "ddProposalStatus";

            ProposalStatusList.DataBind();


        return ProposalStatusList;
    }

    protected void dvProposal_DataRebind()
    {

        string SelectString = "select ProposalNo,ProposalCode, ProposalTitle, YearSubmitted, ProposalStatus, ProposalLink " +
            "from Proposal where ProposalNo=64" ;
        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectString, MyConnection);
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();

            MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet);

            //load into detail view
            dvProposal.DataSource = MyDataSet;
            dvProposal.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
            dvProposal.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
            dvProposal.AutoGenerateInsertButton = true;

            dvProposal.DataBind();

            if (dvProposal.CurrentMode != DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly)
            {

                // add the DropDownList to the DetailView
                DropDownList ProjectProposalList = LoadProposalStatusDropDownList();
                dvProposal.Rows[4].Cells[1].Controls.Add(ProjectProposalList);

                dvProposal.Rows[4].Cells[1].Controls[0].Visible=false;

                ((TextBox)dvProposal.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Enabled = false;

            }

    }


    protected void dvProposal_OnModeChanging(Object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
    {

        dvProposal.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);

        dvProposal_DataRebind();

    }
```

**//give me a NullReferenceException. Cannot find the DropDownList control in the DetailView.**

```
    protected void dvProposal_OnItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {

        string proposalCode = e.Values[1].ToString();
        string proposalTitle = e.Values[2].ToString();
        string YearSubmitted = e.Values[3].ToString();

        **//give me a NullReferenceException. Cannot find the DropDownList control in the DetailView.** 
        string proposalStatus = ((DropDownList)dvProposal.Rows[4].Cells[1].FindControl("ddProposalStatus")).SelectedValue;
        string ProposalLink = e.Values[5].ToString();

        string insertString = " insert into Proposal (ProposalCode, ProposalTitle, YearSubmitted, ProposalStatus, ProposalLink) " +
            "values('" + proposalCode + "','" + proposalTitle + "'," + YearSubmitted + ",'" + proposalStatus + "','" + ProposalLink + "')";


        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertString, MyConnection);
        MyConnection.Open();

            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MyConnection.Close();

            dvProposal_DataRebind();
    }

    protected void dvProposal_OnItemDeleting(object sender, DetailsViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string deleteString = "delete from Proposal where ProposalNo=" + e.Values[0];

        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand(deleteString, MyConnection);
        MyConnection.Open();

        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MyConnection.Close();
        dvProposal_DataRebind();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can control this without all the code-behind using `TemplateField`s for each of the data rows.

Comment: Well, I know I could use TemplateField. Is this the only way? Can I add a control dynamically into a DetailView and get the data later? logically, it should be possible, however, I must miss something to make it work. Or, is this the dead end? And using TemplateField is the only way.

Comment: If you put the DDL in the TemplateField, you know the name of it (so you can use FindControl()), and you can bind to it using Eval() in the markup, saving you a lot of headaches inherent with dynamically-allocated controls.  You could still dynamically generate the controls, but I don't see what it's buying you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Garrison Neely's suggestion. I guess using TemplateField is the fast way for now. So, I modified the code.

test.aspx

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

<asp:DetailsView ID="dvProposal" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="100%"
    OnModeChanging="dvProposal_OnModeChanging" OnItemInserting="dvProposal_OnItemInserting"
    OnItemDeleting="dvProposal_OnItemDeleting" OnDataBound="dvProposal_OnDataBound"  AutoGenerateRows="false">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProposalNo" HeaderText="ProposalNo"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="ProposalCode" HeaderText ="ProposalCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="ProposalTitle" HeaderText ="ProposalTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="YearSubmitted" HeaderText ="YearSubmitted" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="ProposalStatus">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextField ="ProposalStatus" DataValueField ="ProposalStatus" 
                ID="ddlProposalStatus" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextField ="ProposalStatus" DataValueField ="ProposalStatus" 
                ID="ddlProposalStatus" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProposalStatus") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="ProposalLink" HeaderText ="ProposalLink" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
</form>
```

test.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WildfireOperationsResearch"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            dvProposal_DataRebind();
        }
    }



    protected void LoadProposalStatusDropDownList()
    {
        DropDownList ProposalStatusList = (DropDownList)this.dvProposal.FindControl("ddlProposalStatus");
        string SelectString = "select ProposalStatus from ProposalStatus order by ProposalStatus";
        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectString, MyConnection);
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();

            MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet);
            ProposalStatusList.DataSource = MyDataSet;



            ProposalStatusList.DataBind();

            if (dvProposal.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
            {
                DataRowView drv=(DataRowView)this.dvProposal.DataItem;

                ProposalStatusList.Items.FindByValue(drv.Row[4].ToString()).Selected = true;
            }


    }

    protected void dvProposal_DataRebind()
    {

        string SelectString = "select ProposalNo,ProposalCode, ProposalTitle, YearSubmitted, ProposalStatus, ProposalLink " +
            "from Proposal where ProposalNo=64" ;
        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectString, MyConnection);
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();

            MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet);

            //load into detail view

            dvProposal.DataSource = MyDataSet;
            dvProposal.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
            dvProposal.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
            dvProposal.AutoGenerateInsertButton = true;

            dvProposal.DataBind();



    }



    protected void dvProposal_OnDataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dvProposal.CurrentMode != DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly)
        {
            LoadProposalStatusDropDownList();
            ((TextBox)dvProposal.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Enabled = false;

        }

    }

    protected void dvProposal_OnModeChanging(Object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
    {


        dvProposal.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);

        dvProposal_DataRebind();




    }

    protected void dvProposal_OnItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {

        string proposalCode = e.Values[1].ToString();
        string proposalTitle = e.Values[2].ToString();
        string yearSubmitted = e.Values[3].ToString();

        //give me a NullReferenceException. Cannot find the DropDownList control in the DetailView. 
        string proposalStatus = ((DropDownList)dvProposal.Rows[4].Cells[1].FindControl("ddlProposalStatus")).SelectedValue;

        string proposalLink = e.Values[4].ToString();

        string insertString = " insert into Proposal (ProposalCode, ProposalTitle, YearSubmitted, ProposalStatus, ProposalLink) " +
            "values('" + proposalCode + "','" + proposalTitle + "'," + yearSubmitted + ",'" + proposalStatus + "','" + proposalLink + "')";


        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertString, MyConnection);
        MyConnection.Open();

            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();



            MyConnection.Close();

            dvProposal_DataRebind();


    }



    protected void dvProposal_OnItemDeleting(object sender, DetailsViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string deleteString = "delete from Proposal where ProposalNo=" + e.Values[0];

        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand(deleteString, MyConnection);
        MyConnection.Open();

        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MyConnection.Close();


        dvProposal_DataRebind();
    }

}
```